# How to disable triple hashtags (#) in PyCharm for mac

Tags: python, macos, intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm trying to write comments and TODOs on PyCharm for mac and there is this unexpected behaviour:

- When typing a # character it inserts a triple hashtag (###) at the start of the line. It also does not respect the actual indent.
- When commenting a line with cmd + / it only types one hashtag (#) but it also doesn't respect the actual indent.

I want it to behave like it does in Windows, where the # key types only one character and in both cases it respects the actual indent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the behaviour does not look like a default one. Do you have any custom plugins installed?

Please disable all custom plugins, go to **File | Settings | Plugins** click the gear icon and choose "Disable all downloaded plugins", to avoid third-party affection.

> When commenting a line with cmd + / it only types one hashtag (#) but it also doesn't respect the actual indent.

Could you please attach a couple of screenshot examples?

Comment: As you said, the problem was a plugin was automatically added when the settings synced, and this plugin behaves differently in Windows than in MacOS. Thanks!